# Имена людей во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, ономастика

> У нас в коллективе трое Вадимов, трое Даш и трое Ир.

Является ли такое предложение корректным? Выглядит ужасно, но, вероятно, с непривычки.

То есть, вопросов два:

1. Нужно ли использовать прописные (большие) буквы?
2. Можно ли склонять? (Вадимы → Вадимов, Даши → Даш, Иры → Ир)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> У нас в коллективе трое Вадимов, трое Даш и трое Ир

—  выглядит ужасно не из-за прописных букв (а куда ж без них), потому что "трое" девочек не бывает: три.

***У нас в коллективе трое Вадимов, три Даши и три Иры,*** - самое оно!

Склонять можно смело.

А с прописными Вас немножко бес попутал: от имен собственных только избранные прилагательные пишутся со строчной - с суффиксом *-ск-*.

[Вопрос № 256576](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=256576)

> Пожалуйста, уточните, с заглавной или со строчной буквы пишутся
> притяжательные местоимения? Например, "ольгино пальто" или "Ольгино
> пальто"?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Вначале уточним терминологию: это не местоимения, а прилагательные.
> Правила таковы: имена прилагательные, обозначающие индивидуальную
> принадлежность, пишутся с прописной буквы, если они образованы от
> собственных имён при помощи суффикса *-ов (-ев)* или *-ин: Юлина юбка,
> Ольгино пальто, Танина варежка* (в составе фразеологических оборотов
> такие прилагательные пишутся со строчной буквы: *ахиллесова пята,
> сидорова коза*). Если же соответствующие прилагательные имеют в своём
> составе суффикс *-ск-*, они пишутся со строчной буквы: *пушкинские
> стихи, петровские преобразования, булгаковский стиль.*

Добавим про упомянутую "избранность":

[Вопрос № 224804](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=224804)

> В каких случаях московский, пушкинский пишется с прописной, а в каких —
> со строчной буквы? Например, П(п)ушкинские чтения.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Эти слова пишутся с большой буквы, если являются первыми в официальных
> названиях. Верно: *Пушкинские чтения*.

Answer (score 1):

*У нас в коллективе три Вадима, три Даши и три Иры.*

Как бы коллектив не был велик, тёзки не делят его на особые группы. И собирательные числительные в этом случае лучше не употреблять. Но вообще, хоть и очень редко, в литературе они встречаются.

> ― Так ведь и я ― тоже один; не двое Петров Артамоновых живет. [Максим
> Горький. Дело Артамоновых (1924-1925)]

В большинстве примеров, и это подтверждают примеры из НКРЯ, мы видим количественные числительные. Случаи с полными тёзками показывают, что иных решений быть не может.

> Наконец, вышли два Владимира ― Юрьевич и Глебович ― рука в руку. [И.
> Грекова. Перелом (1987)]

> 18 июня 1976 года два ближайших друга Богатырева, два Владимира Николаевича, Корнилов и Войнович, взявшись за руки, идут по двору писательского дома. [Л. К. Чуковская. Процесс исключения (Очерк литературных нравов) (1978)]

> Три князя Василия, три государя Ивана, два царя Фёдора, Борис Годунов,
> Лжедмитрий, император Пётр, две императрицы Екатерины, Анна,
> Елизавета, Павел, три Александра и два Николая ― все как есть. [Лариса
> Васильева. И это — любовь (2007) // «Наука и религия», 2010]